# Chrome Devtools opens as a search rather then the dev tools themselves

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, nativescript

Trying to run a Nativescript debug session and every time I enter

chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000

it opens a google search rather than the debug session.

https://www.google.com/search?q=chrome-devtools%3A%2F%2Fdevtools%2Fbundled%2Finspector.html%3Fexperiments%3Dtrue%26ws%3Dlocalhost%3A41000&oq=chrome-devtools%3A%2F%2Fdevtools%2Fbundled%2Finspector.html%3Fexperiments%3Dtrue%26ws%3Dlocalhost%3A41000&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60j69i61.1074j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Any ideas how to fix this please.

Comment: Which version of Chrome you are using? Are you on Mac? Try replacing chrome-devtools with devtools in the url.

Comment: The `chrome-` prefix was removed in https://crrev.com/748242

Comment: Thank you for that,  I hadn't realised. Begs the question why, when running tns debug, we are still told to use chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000 to open a debug session.

Comment: The reason why, is because this was a change in Chrome 83, which was just released and not everyone has upgraded to 83 yet.   I'm sure the url will be fixed in a future version of tns.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The URL scheme was recently changed to just `devtools://` in [chromium](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/6700d12448f76712c62a6d2372a95b97a26d4779/components/url_formatter/url_fixer.cc#39). The NativeScript CLI v7 has been rereleased to correct this minor change.

Use `devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:41000`.

Comment: Not working for me (tried also with :40000). ERR_INVALID_URL

Answer (score 21):

I was faced with the ERR_INVALID_URL when i tried with @IanMacDonalds answer.

For some reason navigating to the URL without parameters first, loaded devtools properly.

```
devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html
```

Then adding the params on afterwards got the debugging session working again.

```
?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000
```

Hope that helps @Przemo

Comment: This happened for me too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use devtools://devtools/bundled/inspector.html?experiments=true&ws=localhost:40000 in Opera Browse, works fine

Answer (score 0):

Opening an inspector on a random website, and then opening the Nativescript inspector fixed it for me since the latest Chrome release.