# How to run Node packages from Puppeteer client environment for testing purposes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm using [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) to test a client function within a react environment - the function itself doesn't use React, but is meant to be imported in es6 react modules and run inside a end user DOM environment. I need Puppeteer since this function relies on properties such as `innerText`, that aren't available in jsdom.

This function takes a DOM element as an argument, however I am having trouble writing test files for it. Here is a sample of my code:

```js
import path from 'path';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import {getSelectionRange, setSelectionRange} from './selection';

describe(
  'getSelection should match setSelection',
  () => {
    let browser;
    let page;

    beforeAll(async done => {
      try {
        browser = await puppeteer.launch();
        page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(
          `file://${path.join(process.env.ROOT,
          'testFiles/selection_range_test.html')}`
        );
        await page.exposeFunction(
          'setSelectionRange', 
          (el, start, end) => setSelectionRange(el, start, end)
        );
        await page.exposeFunction(
          'getSelectionRange', 
          el => getSelectionRange(el)
        );
      } catch(error) {
        console.error(error);
      }

      done();
    });

    afterAll(async done => {
      await browser.close();
      done();
    });

    it('should match on a node with only one text node children', async () => {
      const {selection, element, argEl} = await page.evaluate(async () => {
        const stn = document.getElementById('single-text-node');

        // Since console.log will output in the Puppeteer browser and not in node console,
        // I added a line inside the selectionRange function to return the element it receives
        // as an argument.
        const argEl = await window.setSelectionRange(stn, 1, 10);

        const selectionRange = await window.getSelectionRange(stn);
        return {selection: selectionRange, element: stn, argEl};
      });

      // Outputs <div id="single-text-node">...</div> 
      // (the content is long so I skipped it, but it displays the correct value here)
      console.log(element.outerHTML);

      // Outputs {}
      console.log(argEl);
    });
  }
);
```

As described in the comments, the element that is directly returned from `page.evaluate()` is correct, but when passed as an argument, the function receives an empty object. I suspect a scope issue but I am totally out of solutions here.

Comment: What happens if you `console.log(argEl)` _inside_ your `evaluate` block? What does it print?

Comment: First of all, you cannot trust console output. It outputs own enumerable properties of an object. If you want to debug a value then debug it with real debugger.

Comment: If I understand correctly, neither exposed functions, nor page.evaluste() can transfer non-serializable values (including DOM elements) between browser and Node.js contexts.

Comment: @SamR. It doesn't print anything to the console, I have to return the value outside evaluate to be able to see it (even printing a hardcoded string wont work).

Comment: @EstusFlask I'm trying to set up a debugger for jest but it will take some time since it doesn't seem quite easy, I'll do an update if it gives me some useful information

Comment: It's actually really simple once you know the exact command. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63671251/unable-to-debug-test-case-using-jest-in-chrome-under-node-devtools

Comment: @vsemozhebuty I actually tried to return a serializable value (in my case .outerHTML, which is a string) from both my exposed function and `page.evaluate`, and they all return undefined. Plus I was able to return `stn` (which is a DOM element and not a serialized sub-property) from `page.evaluate`, and it works like a charm from Node context (`console.log(element.outerHTML)` is called from the test function, which operates in Node). The problem is that, when `stn` is passed as an argument to my exposed function, the exposed function receives an empty object instead of the expected DOM element.

Comment: @vsemozhebuty I have misunderstood something that has been clarified in this post : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48281130/why-cant-i-access-window-in-an-exposefunction-function-with-puppeteer . Turns out `exposeFunction` will run them from Node context and not from page context. I still have issues since calling my functions directly within evaluate fails because of a missing "_selection" reference (which may be used by one of the DOM function I call since I don't have any reference to this property in any of my functions)

Comment: It should print something but in the chrome devtool and not in your terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly I couldn't find any solution that wouldn't invoke transpiling my files, but hopefully I managed to make it work correctly.

The key point was to create a second transpile configuration that will generate a code directly usable by a web browser, using UMD format. Since I use rollup, here is my *rollup,config.js* file:

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import pkg from './package.json';

// The content that is actually exported to be used within a React or Node application.
const libConfig = [
    {
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        input: './src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: './lib/index.js',
                format: 'cjs'
            },
        ],
        external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})],
        plugins: [
            commonjs(),
            resolve(),
            babel({exclude: 'node_modules/**'})
        ]
    }
];

// Used to generate a bundle that is directly executable within a browser environment, for E2E testing.
const testConfig = [
    {
        inlineDynamicImports: true,
        input: './src/index.js',
        output: [
            {
                file: './dist/index.js',
                format: 'umd',
                name: 'tachyon'
            },
        ],
        external: [...Object.keys(pkg.dependencies || {})],
        plugins: [
            commonjs(),
            resolve(),
            babel({runtimeHelpers: true})
        ]
    }
];

const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test' ? testConfig : libConfig;
export default config;
```

I then rewrote my scripts a bit so my test bundle is generated on each test run.

*package.json*

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "build:test": "NODE_ENV=test rollup -c && NODE_ENV=",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "test": "yarn build:test && jest"
  },
}
```

Finally, I added the transpiled script to my *selection_test.html* file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Selection range test</title>
    <script src="../dist/index.js"></script>
</head>
...
```

Which lets me write my test file like this:

```js
import path from 'path';
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import {describe, beforeAll, afterAll, it} from '@jest/globals';

describe(
    'getSelection should match setSelection',
    () => {
        let browser;
        let page;

        beforeAll(async done => {
            try {
                browser = await puppeteer.launch({
                    headless: true,
                    args: ['--disable-web-security', '--disable-features=SameSiteByDefaultCookies,CookiesWithoutSameSiteMustBeSecure'],
                });
                page = await browser.newPage();
                await page.goto(`file://${path.join(process.env.ROOT, 'tests/selection_test.html')}`, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
                await page.setBypassCSP(true);
            } catch(error) {
                console.error(error);
            }

            done();
        });

        afterAll(async done => {
            await browser.close();
            done();
        });

        it('should match on a node with only one text node children', async () => {
            const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
                // Fix eslint warnings.
                window.tachyon = window.tachyon || null;
                if (window.tachyon == null) {
                    return new Error(`cannot find tachyon module`);
                }

                const stn = document.getElementById('single-text-node');
                const witnessRange = tachyon.setRange(stn, 1, 10);
                const selectionRange = tachyon.getRange(stn);

                return {witnessRange, selectionRange, element: stn.outerHTML};
            });

            console.log(data); // Outputs the correct values
            /*
            {
                witnessRange: { start: 1, end: 10 },
                selectionRange: {
                    absolute: { start: 1, end: 10 },
                    start: { container: {}, offset: 1 },
                    end: { container: {}, offset: 10 }
                },
                element: '<div id="single-text-node">Lorem ... sem.</div>'
            }
             */
        });
    }
);
```

The only remaining issue is that `start.container` and `end.container` within the results of `getRange` are undefined, but it seems more likely an issue from puppeteer that cannot handle the Range `startContainer` and `endContainer` properties - I was able to pass DOM references between the content of page.evaluate and my module function without any issues, so it doesn't look like the problem anymore.